# VHDL multiple constant drivers error, which involves 'Z' and 'L'

Tags: vhdl, quartus

To learn VHDL, I'm implementing my own custom CPU with VHDL.

I'm implementing memory-mapped IO, which access traditional RAM and various I/O peripherals as same manner from the viewpoint of user code.

This is implemention of "root" of data address space:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity data_memory_controller is
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        addr: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        rq: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        wq: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        re: in std_logic;
        we: in std_logic;

        ledr: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        sw: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture rtl of data_memory_controller is
    component onchip_ram
        generic (
            addr_width: integer;
            data_width: integer
        );
        port (
            clock: in std_logic;
            addr: in std_logic_vector(addr_width-1 downto 0);
            rq: out std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
            wq: in std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
            re: in std_logic;
            we: in std_logic
        );
    end component;

    component ledr_controller
        port (
            clock: in std_logic;
            rq: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            wq: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            re: in std_logic;
            we: in std_logic;
            ledr: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    component sw_controller
        port (
            clock: in std_logic;
            rq: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            re: in std_logic;
            sw: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    signal c0, c1, c2: std_logic;
    signal rq_tri: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
    c0 <= '1' when std_match(addr, "000000000000000000000000--------") else '0';
    c1 <= '1' when std_match(addr, "10000000000000000000000000000000") else '0';
    c2 <= '1' when std_match(addr, "10000000000000000000000000000001") else '0';

    onchip_ram_c: onchip_ram generic map(
        addr_width => 8,
        data_width => 32
    ) port map (
        clock => clock,
        addr => addr(7 downto 0),
        rq => rq_tri,
        wq => wq,
        re => re and c0,
        we => we and c0
    );

    ledr_controller_c: ledr_controller port map(
        clock => clock,
        rq => rq_tri,
        wq => wq,
        re => re and c1,
        we => we and c1,
        ledr => ledr
    );

    sw_controller_c: sw_controller port map(
        clock => clock,
        rq => rq_tri,
        re => re and c2,
        sw => sw
    );

    rq <= rq_tri;          -- line 90
    rq <= (others => 'L'); -- line 91
end;
```

This is implementation of one of I/O peripheral:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sw_controller is
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        rq: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        re: in std_logic;
        sw: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture rtl of sw_controller is
begin
    process(clock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            if std_match(re, '1') then
                rq <= "0000000000000000000000" & sw;
            else
                rq <= (others => 'Z');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end;
```

Each peripheral accepts read enable signal. if read enable becomes high, it drives `rq` line; otherwise leaves as high-impedance to allow other peripheral can drive.

The purpose of line 90 and line 91 of `data_memory_controller` is that high-impedance state doesn't propagate outside this entity; for the real hardware, this could be implemented by pull-down resistor.

As far as I know, because of resolution rule of `std_logic`, `rq` of `data_memory_controller` become 'L' if there are no peripherals that drives output (= `rq_tri` is 'Z'); otherwise, `rq` copies content of `rq_tri`.

However, the analysis & synthesis step returns the following error:

`Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "rq[31]" at data_memory_controller.vhd(90)
Error (10029): Constant driver at data_memory_controller.vhd(91)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "rq[30]" at data_memory_controller.vhd(90)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "rq[29]" at data_memory_controller.vhd(90)
...... [similar Error (10028) messages] ......`

Yes, I'm "driving" multiple signals on the same line, but I thought there are well-defined rules for this situation and this program should be accepted.

If there were anything wrong what I'm said, please correct me. Moreover, I want to find alternative ways to

1. each peripherals could drive output or 'Z' depends on read enable signal, and
2. not to propagate 'Z' outside `data_memory_controller`

I'm using Quartus Prime Lite Edition version 18.0, and this implementation will be uploaded on the Intel MAX 10 series FPGA chip.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2.4.2 Interpretation of the forcing and weak values ('0', '1', 'L', 'H', FALSE, TRUE) *...A synthesis tool shall interpret the following values as representing a logic value 0: ... — The STD_ULOGIC values '0' and 'L'*. You could do worse than to read through 16.8.2.4 Interpretation of logic values  in it's entirety. Your recourse is to follow Intel's guidelines for when and where you can use multiple driver nets that can go high impedance.

Comment: Are you sure your target FPGA supports internal tri-state buffers?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet :: When I tried removing line 91, I get no error but `Warning (13046): Tri-state node(s) do not directly drive top-level pin(s)` and `Warning (13048): Converted tri-state node "data_memory_controller:data_memory_controller_c|rq[31]" into a selector`.  (Warning 13048 repeats 32 times). My understanding is that the tool will convert 'Z' signal to equivalent elements.

Comment: Althought removing line 91 compiled successfully (with some warning), this leaks 'Z' signal outside data_memory_controller, and I want to prevent it.

Comment: @Venusaur: "_Warning (13046): Tri-state node(s) do not directly drive top-level pin(s)_" looks like your target FPGA has tri-state buffers only in the primary IO pins...

Comment: I think so, and then the tool can convert tri-state to equivalent elements... Then, it is somewhat strange why the tool can't provide proper resolution......

Comment: Anyway, it seems that there are no more 'Z' in the real chip, and my second requirement is (automatically) fulfilled. Thanks for the effort investgating this case.

Answer (score 1):

FPGAs only support tri-state drivers on the pins. While the synth tool may convert internal tri-states to muxes, it doesn't really give a clear design intent for anyone else reading the code. Tri-states should only be used on true inout ports, and only at the top level, with the tri state driver preferably also being in the top level (but it can be moved deeper in the hierarchy if you wish)

You get the multiple drivers because you are driving

```
rq <= rq_tri;          -- line 90
rq <= (others => 'L'); -- line 91
```

This is taking rq_tri value and 0s from the (others 'L') value. 'L' will just be converted to '0' internally, and driven against whatever eq_tri supposed to be. While this may work in simulation, it doesn't meet the expected design patterns in the synthesiser.

If you really want this to work, you could raise an enhancement request with Intel, but I suspect it will be ignored as it doesn't match the *de facto* coding style, which is to have explicit directions for all signals (either in or out).